# How to only print ascii from alt+numpad

Tags: java, character-encoding

Trying to find a way to get my code to print out what I type into it properly. For example: i type "♣" it pops up with "?". I did research but couldn't find anything that relates to this or helps figure this out the way I want it. (Edit: might be my console as some stated, since it worked the same for 2 people)

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    String capital = "";
    int t = 1;

    // Asking for input
    System.out.println("Enter one character");
    capital = in.next();

    if (capital.length() > 1) { // If more than one character is entered. Display error.
        System.out.print("Error! Entered more than one character");
        t = 0;
    }

    if (capital.length() < 1) {// If less than one character is entered. Display error.
        System.out.print("Error! Entered less than one character");
        t = 0;
    }

    if (t == 1) { // If no errors. Proceed to print out outcome
        System.out.print("You Entered: ");
        System.out.print(capital);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is '♣' an ascii character? Perhaps you are looking for utf-8 encoding.

Comment: I think you don't mean ASCII.  ASCII can only represent a small set of characters, and "♣" isn't one of them.  Also, is this just a problem of getting what you type in to show up correctly when you print it, or do you want to print the representation of that character numerically?

Comment: What does 'pops up with "?"' mean?  When I run your code, it does the right thing.  It prints whatever character I type into it, including '♣'.  Please clarify your question.

Comment: I think that you should read more about charsets and charset representation on console or terminals. But it is unrelated to ASCII (the ASCII characters are precisely the characters that are available on all common and current charsets) and to Java...

Comment: Your code is working correctly. The problem might come from the console you are using. This console can't (or is not configure to) display this character. But your code does get and display back correctly

Comment: @vincrichaud oh, then yeah probably my console. i`ll put a screenshot to show what pops up for me. http://prntscr.com/n3qewh

Comment: @Steve as vin said, probably just my console then if 2 people got it to work properly.

Comment: As an experiment, try `System.out.println((int) capital.charAt(0));`.  If it prints 9827, your code works, but the console can’t display the ♣ character.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you are using eclipse IDE? If so: Go to Run -> Run configurations -> In your Mainclass -> click on "Common"-Tab -> in the field "Encoding" -> Set this to "UTF-8" -> Save with "Apply"

Your console should output ♣

Other IDE should have a similar option.

Comment: Worked. Thank you <3

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing here that has anything to do with ASCII.  Character encodings are systems that map numeric values to particular visual characters.  ASCII is the most limited of character encodings. It can only represent 127 unique values. These include the standard characters A-Z, a-z, 0-9, basic punctuation, etc.

Unicode is a character encoding that can encode a much larger variety of characters, including '♣'.  Java strings use the Unicode encoding, so they can represent all of the characters that that character set can encode, which is just about any character known to man.  There is a subtle problem here in that there are really two versions of Unicode, Unicode 16 and Unicode 32.  This is because even with 16 bits, the world ran out of space to put all of the characters that existed.  So Unicode 32 was added on.  Most characters fit in Unicode 16, so this usually isn't an issue either way.

To print the Unicode numeric representation of a character in a Java string, you can just do this:

```
System.out.println("♣".codePointAt(0));
```

In this case, you get:

```
9827
```

so 9827 is the Unicode numeric representation of '♣'.

Comment: Thanks didn't know, teacher called them ascii, good to learn something new. Thanks <3 i`ll change the title and my question up so it doesn't confuse people.

Comment: Great!  Glad I could help.  Please feel free to put more in your question if you need more info.  Also, if this really helped you, please consider clicking the "check mark" to say it helped and answered your question.

Comment: @QuaccasaurusRex "ASCII" meaning ASCII is almost as rare as actually using ASCII. When you hear "ASCII", ask for the spec that says ASCII applies to the situation or assume that it's not ASCII and ask for the actual character set and encoding.